# Android: non-stop location calculation

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm currently doing a project of robotics and I decided to drive my robots thanks to an Android Phone (Samsung Galaxy S). My problem is that I can't find the way to calculate the GPS location "everytime", I mean, the driving requires a very tiny refresh-time, and I can't get it. At first, I thought I just had to put something like this:

```
mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, this.refreshTime, 0, this);
```

With refreshTime being a variable instant which values is 500 e.g., but it doesn't work, as I noticed this value is just a hint, not really a parameter. So i'm lost ^^

Is there any way to do that ?

I profit in this topic to ask you a question... Do you know guys why my location is not being calculated when I set GPS_PROVIDER ? My satellites are turned on but nothing got returned so I guess I'm doing wrong...

Here's my complete code:

```
package com.pIndus.gps;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Loc extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

private long refreshTime = 1000;
private LocationManager mLocManager;
private LocationListener mLocListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */

    mLocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    mLocListener = new MyLocationListener();

    mLocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, this.refreshTime, 0, mLocListener);

}

/* Class My Location Listener */

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

{



    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {

        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps désactivé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        Log.i("GPS", "GPS Desactivé");

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {

        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps activé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("GPS", "GPS Activé");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Statut changé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("GPS", "Statut changé");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

    {

        loc.getLatitude();

        loc.getLongitude();

        String Text = "Localisation courante:\n " + "Latitude : " + loc.getLatitude() + "\n" + "Longitude : " + loc.getLongitude();

        Log.i("GPS", "Localisation calculée");

        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }





}



public void onPause()
{
    mLocManager.removeUpdates(mLocListener);
    super.onPause();
}

public void onStop()
{
    mLocManager.removeUpdates(mLocListener);
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

Hope you guys understood me, I know my english is very bad.

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: You already posted this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209722/android-non-stop-location-calculation

Comment: Oh sorry I did a mistake ith the edit button. I asked the other thread to be deleted, again sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get much greater frequency than 1Hz... GPS receiver chips usually send the measurements (logically) on a serial line at regular intervals, so there is no way of telling it "I want a location, NOW". This regular interval is adjustable, too, but it seems unlikely that the OS is willing to adjust it to a much smaller value than 1Hz, just because some app requested.

However, since GPS fixes aren't that accurate anyway, this doesn't seem to be a problem that big. (Unless you're building a jet-powered robot aircraft that flies 200 meters in half a second, of course :))

I would suggest using a Kalman filter or a similar method to extrapolate the position based on the previous fixes and speed. (If you add some more info from other sensors, motor control etc, this estimate may be much better than the one you could get by measuring GPS position 10 times a second.)

Comment: I'm going to check this option. And no, it won't be an aircraft but buggies which have to communicate with eachother and act according to some strategies i've already developped. I thought GPS was accurate enough.